# Disable Calendar notifications

Tags: android, android-calendar

Hi I'm adding an event to the Calendar with hasAlarm = 0 but I still receive a notification about the event in the status bar. Here's my code:

```
        ContentValues values_cal = new ContentValues();
    values_cal.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values_cal.put("title", event);
    values_cal.put("dtstart", eventDateTimeStart);
    values_cal.put("dtend", eventDateTimeEnd);
    values_cal.put("hasAlarm", 0);
    values_cal.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

    Uri cal_uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
        cal_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), values_cal);
    else
        cal_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), values_cal);
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or hasAlarm has nothing to do with the event reminder (notification). How can I disable this notifications?

Comment: Are you testing on a customized phone like HTC or Samsung? Can you try it in the emulator? Also what is the minimum API level you need to target?

Comment: Im testing on Nexus 4, min API 7

Comment: Thats odd, the calendar will not have a reminder unless you manually insert one in the reminders content provider (content://com.android.calendar/reminders)

Comment: Did your phone maybe receive the default reminders from Google Calendar? I think it may be possible that after syncing the event with Google Calendar, the default reminders were added. Please try to do the same while your phone is not connected to the Internet. Do you still get a notification for the event?